# Can't open Blender through VS Code

Tags: python

Trying to launch Blender through VS Code, getting this error. Tried removing new code, reinstalling VSCode, even with other scripts. Anyone got this error?

```
Read prefs: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\python
register_class(...):
Warning: 'DNOISEPanel' doesn't contain '_PT_' with prefix & suffix
registering drivers
registering drivers
[{'load_dir': 'c:\\Users\\USER\\VS Code Projects\\Python\\HeritageAddon', 'module_name': 'HeritageAddon'}]
c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\jacqueslucke.blender-development-0.0.12\pythonFiles\include\blender_vscode\environment.py:5: RuntimeWarning: Use 'sys.executable' instead of 'binary_path_python'!
  python_path = Path(bpy.app.binary_path_python)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\jacqueslucke.blender-development-0.0.12\pythonFiles\launch.py", line 18, in <module>
    allow_modify_external_python=os.environ['ALLOW_MODIFY_EXTERNAL_PYTHON'] == "yes",
  File "c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\jacqueslucke.blender-development-0.0.12\pythonFiles\include\blender_vscode\__init__.py", line 14, in startup
    path_mappings = load_addons.setup_addon_links(addons_to_load)
  File "c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\jacqueslucke.blender-development-0.0.12\pythonFiles\include\blender_vscode\load_addons.py", line 20, in setup_addon_links
    create_link_in_user_addon_directory(source_path, load_path)
  File "c:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\jacqueslucke.blender-development-0.0.12\pythonFiles\include\blender_vscode\load_addons.py", line 43, in create_link_in_user_addon_directory
    _winapi.CreateJunction(str(directory), str(link_path))
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Can't open a file that doesn't exist
Saved session recovery to 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\quit.blend'
```